# Flutter: Links in long text like Privacy policy and Tems of Service

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make privacy policy and terms of service link.

```
 Widget privacyPolicyLinkAndTermsOfService() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'By continuing, you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy.',
          style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In this way the text doesn't overflow but I cannot make a part of text link. So I tried to use `Row` and separate the text and the link part as children.
However, the text overflows when I use `Row` and separate text as children.
How can I prevent them from overflowing while making a part of text link?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `RichText` class to link parts of text. It's constructor `text.rich` allows us to style different parts of the text. Below is the working code that only shows links for `Terms of Service` and `Privacy Policy` which user can tap on to open respective links and rest of the text is plain text:

```
Widget privacyPolicyLinkAndTermsOfService() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Center(
      child: Text.rich(
        TextSpan(
          text: 'By continuing, you agree to our ', style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black
        ),
          children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Terms of Service', style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black,
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            ),
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () {
                // code to open / launch terms of service link here
                }
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: ' and ', style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black
            ),
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Privacy Policy', style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline
                ),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                    // code to open / launch privacy policy link here
                      }
                )
              ]
            )
          ]
        )
      )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Above code is rendered in UI as:

[image]

`TapGestureRecognizer()` method requires you to import below file:

`import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';`

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is now broken.  inlining the TapGestureRecognizer will no longer work. it needs to be set as a variable.